# Managing sessions between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel

I need to "attach" some new pages created in ASP.NET Core MVC into an already running ASP.NET app. Regarding this, I guess, one interesting approach is using IIS as a reverse proxy to redirect requests to the Kestrel server where the ASP.NET Core app is running.

The problem I have here is that I have absolutely no idea about the relationship between the sessions used in this bidirectional communication process:

1. When using IIS as a reverse proxy, can an IIS session be used to control whether a user can or can't access the pages allocated in Kestrel when that user is already navigating through the pages allocated in that Kestrel?
2. If not, is there any "clean" way to "communicate" both IIS and Kestrel sessions directly or am I forced to use some kind of distributed-cache system like Redis or SQL Server? What about updating both session timeouts when navigating when the user is not "jumping" from one server to the other one so that the session timeout can be reset? Any ideas on how could this be overcome?
3. Talking about the redirections themselves: When using the reverse proxy approach in IIS, if I want to travel from an ASP.NET Core page to another one, should I use the MVC action (as usual) or should I redirect using the URL from which the IIS proxy would redirect to the target action itself?

As you all can see, I'm an absolute newbie with these technologies and I'm still studying how to conceptually solve these issues before rolling up my sleeves, so I have no code written yet.

Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest following the help links to get advice on phrasing a question and title to increase the chances of getting a response and fit with site style. Surprisingly, the politeness in your last lines is not consistent with site style.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer and your advice, espertus!
Ok, I'll check those links and edit both, title and questions, in order to be more consistent with the site style.
I did not mean to express myself as a Brittish Sir, so I will try not to do that from now on :-D